# How do I set a background image in a website after having divs placed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set a picture for the background of a homepage on my website. How can I do this if I previously had just background colors set? I want the picture to run in the first div and the navigation.
Here is what it looks like currently:

[home page link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQQXH.png)

here is the code for it.

```css
.body{ 
  background-image: url("https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.first-box{
grid-area: first-box;
align-content: center;
padding: 65px 300px;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>

                </div>
                <div class="name" data-text="fa-home">Home</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <!--I have used icons with the navigations as it makes it easier for dyslexic people to navigate. -->
        <li><a href="tryhelp.html">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-magic"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="name" data-text="fa-magic">Try our solutions </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="emergency-contacts.html">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-child"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="name" data-text="fa-child">Emergency Contacts</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="learnmore.html">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
                    <!--place it in the center in css, this is a self reminder (delete later)-->
                </div>
                <div class="name" data-text="fa-book">Learn More</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <div class="logo">
            <img class="img1" src="photos/logo2.png" alt="the logo">
        </div>
</div>
<!--navigation ends here-->
<div class="first-box">
    <div class="intro intro1">Welcome!</div>
    <div class="intro intro2">
        <span class="sub-head "> We care about you</span>
        <span class="sub-head inactive">becuase you matter</span>
        <!-- lol dramatic effect-->
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried putting the image in the body of the file in CSS and making the other divs transparent for the background but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: your `.body`  has dot. it should have been `body`

Answer (score 0):

You have written style for `.body` class not for `body` tag. Either you have to change as `tag` style or you need to add a class `body` in your body tag.

```css
body{ 
  background-image: url("https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.first-box{
grid-area: first-box;
align-content: center;
padding: 65px 300px;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>

                </div>
                <div class="name" data-text="fa-home">Home</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <!--I have used icons with the navigations as it makes it easier for dyslexic people to navigate. -->
        <li><a href="tryhelp.html">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-magic"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="name" data-text="fa-magic">Try our solutions </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="emergency-contacts.html">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-child"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="name" data-text="fa-child">Emergency Contacts</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="learnmore.html">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
                    <!--place it in the center in css, this is a self reminder (delete later)-->
                </div>
                <div class="name" data-text="fa-book">Learn More</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <div class="logo">
            <img class="img1" src="photos/logo2.png" alt="the logo">
        </div>
</div>
<!--navigation ends here-->
<div class="first-box">
    <div class="intro intro1">Welcome!</div>
    <div class="intro intro2">
        <span class="sub-head "> We care about you</span>
        <span class="sub-head inactive">becuase you matter</span>
        <!-- lol dramatic effect-->
    </div>
</div>
```